# Como compilar/buildar uma DLL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

Fiz um programa em C# no Visual Studio 2017, mas como padrão, quando eu compilo o código, ele cria um arquivo `.exe`, mas eu gostaria que o código compilasse um arquivo `.dll`. Como posso fazer isso?

**Exemplo:**

Criei um programa chamado `ccleaner`.

Quando aperto `CTRL + SHIFT + B` (comando para compilar o projeto), ele me cria um executável no seguinte diretório:

```
C:\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ccleaner\ccleaner\bin\Debug\ccleaner.exe
```

Mas o que eu quero criar é:

```
C:\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ccleaner\ccleaner\bin\Debug\ccleaner.dll
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa de criar um projeto do tipo ClassLibrary

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

em um projeto já existente, você pode alterar o output type na propriedade do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e sim, ao compilar, será gerada uma dll

Comment: Ta, e ai? O que eu faço depois? Já vai vim compilando como dll por padrão?

Comment: atualizei, se o tipo de saída for class library, sim, será compilada como dll